# Trying to Run Google App Engine behind a proxy, errors received

Tags: python, google-app-engine, proxy

I am running Python 2.6.1 on my computer, and just installed google App Engine.

As soon as I click on the App Engine Launcher, it gives an error dialog box and asks me to check the `GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe` file for more details.

I have appended the log file below:

```
File "GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py", line 42, in <module>
File "wx\_core.pyc", line 7913, in __init__
File "wx\_core.pyc", line 7487, in _BootstrapApp
File "launcher\app.pyc", line 58, in OnInit
File "launcher\app.pyc", line 152, in _VersionCheck
File "urllib.pyc", line 82, in urlopen
File "urllib.pyc", line 190, in open
File "urllib.pyc", line 338, in open_http
File "urllib.pyc", line 351, in http_error
File "urllib.pyc", line 702, in http_error_407
File "urllib.pyc", line 714, in retry_proxy_http_basic_auth
File "urllib.pyc", line 773, in get_user_passwd
File "urllib.pyc", line 782, in prompt_user_passwd
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

From the file, I get the feeling that it's about giving the right proxy details.

I have checked up http://code.google.com/p/google-appengine-wx-launcher/issues/detail?id=17
and http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=544.

It seems that it is about making some edits to some particular .py file so that I can enter my proxy settings, and username/password.

I have also come across few suggestions telling me to set the proxy in environment variables at the command prompt - but that hasn't worked. Any suggestions, please?

UPDATE:
I came across the following at nomagon dot com /?p=5 I am using it but unable to make sense out of the appcfg.py file

If your're not behind a proxy, then your ok to go! You can use the deploy button inside the App Engine Launcher, however if you're behind a proxy, you will need to set some variables

```
In a CMD window:
set HTTP_PROXY=<proxy>
set HTTPS_PROXY=<prox>
In a CMD window:
appcfg.py update <path to app>
```

Comment: Thanks @eldareatthis : I was trying to edit it myself :-)

Comment: If you have an answer, you should post it as one, not as an update to the question.

Comment: It's not an answer. I am still unable to access ANYTHING! The error 407 persists.