# Google App engine Launcher startup error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new to Python and not so experienced. I recently installed the Google App Engine Launcher on Windows 7 (64 bit) and I have Python 2.7 installed. When I start the Google App Engine Launcher , I get an error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py", line 42, in <module>
File "wx\_core.pyc", line 7913, in __init__
File "wx\_core.pyc", line 7487, in _BootstrapApp
File "launcher\app.pyc", line 58, in OnInit
File "launcher\app.pyc", line 152, in _VersionCheck
File "urllib.pyc", line 82, in urlopen
File "urllib.pyc", line 190, in open
File "urllib.pyc", line 338, in open_http
File "urllib.pyc", line 351, in http_error
File "urllib.pyc", line 702, in http_error_407
File "urllib.pyc", line 714, in retry_proxy_http_basic_auth
File "urllib.pyc", line 773, in get_user_passwd
File "urllib.pyc", line 782, in prompt_user_passwd
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Can anyone please help me out , I tried Googling but couldnt get any satisfying answer.

Comment: You might need to monkeypatching urllib or setting up your proxy setting in the environment. Those links could be helpful: [udacity post](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/6027846/running-app-engine-from-behind-a-proxy), [a patch from googlecode](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=4849) and [similiar SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919388/trying-to-run-google-app-engine-behind-a-proxy-errors-received).

Comment: Yes ,I am behind my University proxy , can you please tell me how to give the application the authentication to the proxy

Comment: Thanks :) I got it from the link you gave me . Thanks a lot